# Loading an assembly generated by the Roslyn compiler

Tags: c#, assemblies, roslyn

I'm generating a Greeter.dll using the Roslyn compiler. My problem occurs trying to load the DLL file.

Here's the code:

```
using System;

using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;

using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

namespace LoadingAClass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(@"
class Greeter
{
    static void Greet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World"");
    }
}");

            var compilation = Compilation.Create("Greeter.dll",
                syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
                references: new[] {
                    new AssemblyFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                    new AssemblyFileReference(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location),
                });

            Assembly assembly;
            using (var file = new FileStream("Greeter.dll", FileMode.Create))
            {
                EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(file);
            }

            assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Greeter.dll"));
            Type type = assembly.GetType("Greeter");
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            type.InvokeMember("Greet",
                BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                null,
                obj,
                null);

            Console.WriteLine("<ENTER> to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
    // Thanks, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/11/23/using-the-roslyn-symbol-api.aspx
}
```

The error message occurs on the line `assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Greeter.dll"));` and reads

> Im Modul wurde ein Assemblymanifest erwartet. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131018)

Which roughly translates to

> An assembly manifest was expected in the module.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: You have several mistakes in your code. Apparently, you already figured them out (but needing a PDB was not among them). Next time, look at `result.Diagnostics` to find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been adding Roslyn support to the [O2 Plarform](http://diniscruz.blogspot.co.uk/p/o2-platform.html) and here is how you can use its Roslyn support to compile (code), create (and assembly) and invoke (its method) one line of code:

```
return @"using System; class Greeter { static string Greet() {  return ""Another hello!!""; }}"
        .tree().compiler("Great").create_Assembly().type("Greeter").invokeStatic("Greet"); 

//O2Ref:O2_FluentSharp_Roslyn.dll
```

Here is a version that executes a code snippet that looks like yours (I added a return value):

```
panel.clear().add_ConsoleOut();
var code = @"
using System;
class Greeter
{
    static string Greet()
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World""); 
        return ""hello from here"";
    }
}";
var tree = code.astTree();
if (tree.hasErrors())
    return tree.errors();   

var compiler = tree.compiler("Great")
                   .add_Reference("mscorlib");

if (compiler.hasErrors()) 
    return compiler.errors();    

var assembly  =tree.compiler("Great")
                   .create_Assembly();

return assembly.type("Greeter")
               .invokeStatic("Greet"); 

//O2Ref:O2_FluentSharp_Roslyn.dll
//O2File:_Extra_methods_Roslyn_API.cs
//O2File:API_ConsoleOut.cs
```

For a couple more details and screenshots of what this looks like, see this blog post: [1 line to compile, create and execute: O2 Script to use Roslyn to Dynamically compile and execute a method](http://diniscruz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/1-line-to-compile-create-and-execute-o2.html)

**UPDATE:** see http://blog.diniscruz.com/search/label/Roslyn for a large number number of Roslyn related posts and tools (created using the O2 Platform)

Answer (score 16):

I stumbled across this and, even though you have an accepted answer, I don't think it's helpful in general.  So, I'll just leave this here for future searchers like myself.

The problem with the code is two things, which you would have found out by looking at the returned value from

```
EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(file);
```

If you look at the properties on the EmitResult object, you would have found that there were 2 errors in the results.Diagnostics member.

1. Main method not found
2. Couldn't find class Console

So, to fix the problem,
1. You need to mark the output as a dll
2. You need to add 'using System;' to the code you're passing into the API or say 'System.Console.WriteLine'

The following code works making changes to fix those two issues:

```
        var outputFile = "Greeter.dll";
        var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(@"
 // ADDED THE FOLLOWING LINE
using System;

class Greeter
{
    public void Greet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World"");
    }
}");
        var compilation = Compilation.Create(outputFile,
            syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
            references: new[] {
                new AssemblyFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                new AssemblyFileReference(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location),
            },

// ADDED THE FOLLOWING LINE
            options: new CompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

        using (var file = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(file);
        }

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Greeter.dll");

        Type type = assembly.GetType("Greeter");
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        type.InvokeMember("Greet",
            BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null,
            obj,
            null);

        Console.WriteLine("<ENTER> to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new API for the References that looks like this:

```
var compilation = Compilation.Create(outputFile,
    syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
    references: new[] {
        new MetadataFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
        new MetadataFileReference(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location),
    },
    options: new CompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
);
```

This is with the latest Roslyn-CTP 2012 in Sept...

Answer (score 0):

This code worked beautifully:

```
using System;

using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;

using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

namespace LoadingAClass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(@"
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Greeter
    {
        public static void Greet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World"");
        }
    }
}");

            string dllPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Greeter.dll");
            string pdbPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Greeter.pdb");

            var compilation = Compilation.Create(dllPath,
                new CompilationOptions(
                    assemblyKind: AssemblyKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary
                ))
                .AddSyntaxTrees( syntaxTree )
                .AddReferences(new AssemblyFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
                .AddReferences(new AssemblyFileReference(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location));

            EmitResult result;

            using (FileStream dllStream = new FileStream(dllPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            using (FileStream pdbStream = new FileStream(pdbPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                result = compilation.Emit(
                    executableStream: dllStream,
                    pdbFileName: pdbPath,
                    pdbStream: pdbStream);
            }

            if (result.Success)
            {
                //assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Greeter.dll"));
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"Greeter.dll");

                Type type = assembly.GetType("HelloWorld.Greeter");
                var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                type.InvokeMember("Greet",
                    BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                    null,
                    obj,
                    null);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Go");
                Console.WriteLine(result.Diagnostics.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("<ENTER> to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
    // Thanks, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/11/23/using-the-roslyn-symbol-api.aspx
    // Thanks, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/roslyn/thread/d620a4a1-3a90-401b-b946-bfa1fc6ad7a2
}
```

Comment: Just a piece of code with no explanation is not very useful. Does this mean you solved your problem? Or is this supposed to be just an extension of the question?

Comment: Note that in the CompilationsOptions the AssemblyKind has been renamed to : OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary

Comment: For reference one of the issues with the original code was the not definition of the OutputKind (since one of the errors was the need to have a static Main method)

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I needed to create a pdb file.

```
using (FileStream dllStream = new FileStream(dllPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
using (FileStream pdbStream = new FileStream(pdbPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    result = compilation.Emit(
       executableStream: dllStream,
       pdbFileName: pdbPath,
       pdbStream: pdbStream);
}
```