# Can you cache compiled code to execute against different Session/hostObject?

Tags: c#, roslyn

We currently use IronPython as a scripting language to allow our business users to configure large portions of our application and we are evaluating the possibility of adding in C# as a scripting language once Roslyn is released.  For IronPython, we use `Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.CompiledCode` to cache the compiled code and execute it against different `ScriptScope` object.

Looking around the latest Rosyln CTP I don't see an obvious way to compile code and then execute it against different `Sessions` or `hostObjects`. Is this functionality available at this time, and if not, is it going to be available at release?

Comment: We can't answer questions about the future. Nobody knows what's going to be available when Roslyn is released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We currently are looking at supporting the same scenario with the Roslyn Scripting APIs, that is, to compile the code so that you can execute it independently against different scopes.  It will likely be a bit different than the DLR Hosting APIs, and by the time we ship, plans could completely change.  I should post my updated scripting spec.  I haven't done so already since we did not do much work on the Interactive/scripting area for CTP2, focusing ore on the compiler APIs.  We have sketched out the direction we're thinking in regards to your question.  I'll try to do that today, so on the Roslyn forum, see the pinned post at the top of the forum, which I'll update with a link to the updated spec.

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: Thanks Bill!  Just so you know, I'm holding my breath until this is released. Your move.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a whole lot about Roslyn but it looks like this would accomplish what you're after. [Loading an assembly generated by the Roslyn compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751079/loading-an-assembly-generated-by-the-roslyn-compiler)