# How Do I make a Dynamically Compiled Class emit to a DLL

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have some data that I uses to create a program.  For the purposes of example this is the generated code:

```
using System;

namespace MyNamespace {
    public class BuiltProgram{
        public bool Eval(int x, int y, int z, out int ret) {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
            ret = x + y + z;
            return true;
        }    
    }
}
```

The code that I use to generate it is the following:

```
var factory = new ProgramFactory(tree);
var newProgram = factory.GetCompiledProgram();

// Program parsing code...
SyntaxTree programSyntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(newProgram);
var outputFile = "Compiled.dll";
var compilation = Compilation.Create(outputFile,
    options: new CompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary),
    syntaxTrees: new[] { programSyntaxTree }
);

FileStream file;
using (file = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create)) {
    EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(file);
}
// THIS CODE BREAKS:
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file.Name);

Type type = assembly.GetType("BuiltProgram");
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
int ret = 0;
type.InvokeMember("Eval",
    BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    null,
    obj,
    args: new[] {
        (object)5,
        (object)10,
        (object)2,
        ret
    }
);
```

It breaks on the assembly line because it says that it doesn't have the assembly manifest, but I look at the "Compiled.dll" and there is no data in it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11474915/1529246

Comment: you are probably missing the assembly references

Comment: Indeed, as @YK1 mentioned, you'll need to add some assembly references - at least for mscorlib.dll.  Take a look at the diagnostics in the EmitResult and make sure there are no errors before trying to lead the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add reference to mscorlib.

This will make it work:

```
 var compilation = Compilation.Create(outputFile,
                options: new CompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary),
                syntaxTrees: new[] { programSyntaxTree },
                references: new [] { new MetadataFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location) }
        );
```

While accesing your type, also add namespace.

```
Type type = assembly.GetType("MyNamespace.BuiltProgram");
```

You may have difficulty getting out parameter value. See [this](http://developerexperience.blogspot.in/2006/05/out-ref-and-invokemember.html).

Comment: In general, check your EmitResult to verify everything actually emitted how you thought it should.